# ¿Cómo sustituir en una cadena todas las expresiones contenidas en un array?

Tags: javascript, array, string, bucle-for

A ver si alguien experto me puede ayudar con este problema:

Me gustaría sustituir una cadena por determinadas expresiones contenidas en un array (si éstas coinciden con la cadena). Lo estoy haciendo así, pero se me repite la cadena (porque está en el bucle for que uso para recorrer el array):

```
expresiones = ['naranja limones', 'fresa frambuesa'];

frase = 'naranja limones fresa frambuesa';

function sustituye(fr, expr){
   for(i=0;i<expr.length;i++){
      if(fr.includes(expr[i])==true){
         y = fr.replace(expr[i], expr[i].split(' ').join('-'));
         document.write(y);
      }
   }
}

sustituye(frase, expresiones);
```

Quiero obtener esto:

naranja-limones fresa-frambuesa

pero me sale esto:

naranja-limones fresa frambuesanaranja limones fresa-frambuesa

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes un pequeño fallo en las sustituciones pues el split parte la expresión validada y reemplazas una parte de ella. Adicionalmente, el modo como usas los nombres hace que las asignaciones de sustitución no sean claras.
Te voy a ofrecer una variante del código muy elemental que hace la sustitución correcta:

```js
 

function sustituye(fr, expr){
    var reemplazo;
    // Uso un ciclo sin índices que me parece más cómodo porque
    // en este caso los índices carecen de uso.
    for(let buscar of expr){
        // Crea la variable de sustitución
        reemplazo = buscar.replace(' ', '-');
        // Verifica si hay o no coincidencia
        if(fr.includes(buscar)==true){
            // Si la hay hace el reemplazo
            fr = fr.replace(buscar, reemplazo);
        }// cierra validación
    }// cierra ciclo for
    // devuelve la cadena modificada
    return fr;
}//cierra la función sustituye
expresiones = ['naranja limones', 'fresa frambuesa'];
frase = 'naranja limones fresa frambuesa';
console.log(sustituye(frase, expresiones));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Quevedo. Me acabas de sacar de un problema. Lo único que no entiendo del código es la parte de:  for(let buscar of expr){... y por qué la función replace, estando dentro del bucle, no repite la cadena como me sucedía a mí. ¿Podrías hacer esa parte del código sin let (que no entiendo) con una variable normal? ¿Y qué es ese tipo bucle for ... of (que tampoco entiendo)? ¿Cómo sería el código javascript tradicional? Saludos

Comment: Me alegra @PabloDavidMartín el bucle for ... of, es idéntico al tradicional sólo que asigna nombres en lugar de recorrer índices `i` y los valores son objetos denominados por el nombre que se asigne en el ciclo.